# ajaxForm not working

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

Here is my ajaxForm code

```
 var qx = $('#XText').attr('value');

    $.ajax({

     type: "post",
     url: "qsubmit.php",
     data: "q="+qx,
     success: function() {

     }
    });
```

And the insert code

```
include('db-config.php');

$q = $_POST['q'];


 $insert_ann = sprintf("INSERT INTO med_tab (med_title) VALUES ('$q')");
 mysql_select_db($database_med_pharm, $med_pharm);
 $Result1 = mysql_query($insert_ann, $med_pharm) or die(mysql_error());
```

For some reason this is not working not sure why, any and all assistance would be great.

I want to pass in 2 values in `data: "q="+qx,` in the ajax js, how do I get that done.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: What errors do you get? What exactly is not working?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @pekka Data is not being inserted

@Slaks Could you tell me point me to the correct the error and where the error is exactly, thanks in advance.

Comment: `$q = $_POST['q']; $insert_ann = sprintf("INSERT INTO med_tab (med_title) VALUES ('$q')");` is the vulnerable code, you're inserting based on POST values which could easily be forged.

Comment: @cyclone Do I put an if?

Comment: @Jean Try to validate the $_POST data as being valid data first. Use regex to make sure it is valid, or even just sanitize the data with `addslashes` or `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are talking about the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) your code should simply look like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#idofyourform').ajaxForm(function(result) {
        alert('form successfully submitted');
    });
});
```

If not, then make sure you properly encode the request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "qsubmit.php",
    data: { q1: 'value 1', q2: 'value 2' },
    success: function(result) {
        alert('form successfully submitted');
    }
});
```

or if you want to send the contents of the form:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "qsubmit.php",
    data: $('#idoftheform').serialize(),
    success: function(result) {
        alert('form successfully submitted');
    }
});
```

Finally, make sure you have installed [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to better analyze what's happening under the covers.

Comment: For some reason there is no alert from $.ajax{} also no insert, guess the ajaxform is not being triggered for some reason

Comment: @Jean, FireBug will indicate if there are some errors. Are there any?

Comment: It was not an issue with the coding error, but a braces closed after the $.ajax.

Comment: @Darin.. Thanks for helping out..
Does not chrome have a firebug.

Comment: @Jean, you may checkout the [Google Chrome Developer Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/).